# iOS - NSString regex match

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring, match

I have a string for example:

```
NSString *str = @"Strängnäs"
```

Then I use a method for replace scandinavian letters with `*`, so it would be:

```
NSString *strReplaced = @"Str*ngn*s"
```

I need a function to match `str` with `strReplaced`. In other words, the `*` should be treated as any character ( `*` should match with any character).

How can I achieve this?

```
Strängnäs should be equal to Str*ngn*s
```

EDIT:

Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I want `*` to be treated as any character. So when doing `[@"Strängnäs" isEqualToString:@"Str*ngn*s"]` it should return `YES`

Comment: Have you thought about processing your string in ASCII (7 bits) (All Scandinavian chars will be replaced with ?) and then replace all the ? with *.

Comment: It is still not clear what you want to do. What are "Scandinavian" letters, do you have a Unicode range, or just a list of them? Do you want to just replace them in some input string with asterisks? Then why the first `Strängnäs` still has the `ä`? Please be specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following regex pattern will match all non-ASCII text considering that Scandinavian letters are not ASCII:

`[^ -~]`

Treat each line separately to avoid matching the newline character and replace the matches with *.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dI6zN5/1

**Edit:**

Here's an optimized pattern based on the above one:

```
[^\000-~]
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/lO0bE9/1

**Edit 1:** As per your comment, you need a UDF (User defined function) that:

- takes in the Scandinavian string
- converts all of its Scandinavian letters to *
- takes in the string with the asterisks
- compares the two strings
- return `True` if the two strings match, else false.

You can then use the UDF like `CompareString(ScanStr,AsteriskStr)`.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But that is not the issue, check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a code example using the regex posted by **[JLILI Amen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3704475/jlili-amen)**

### Code

```
NSString *string = @"Strängnäs";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^ -~]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"*"];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

### Output

```
Str*ngn*s
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But that is not the issue, maybe I wasnt clear enough. My question is, how can I make the * be treated as any character when using isEqualToString. Ex: *ke should be equal to Åke, Ske, Kke etc. Here * can be Å,S or K.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are after, but maybe this will help.

The regular expression pattern which matches anything is`.` (dot), so you can create a pattern from your `strReplaced` by replacing the `*`'s with `.`'s:

```
NSString *pattern = [strReplaced stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"*" withString:"."];
```

Now using `NSRegularExpression` you can construct a regular expression from `pattern` and then see if `str` matches it - see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html) for the required methods.

Comment: No. That's what he is looking for. He is trying to replace all Scandinavians letters with *.

Comment: @JLILIAmen - Well I'm not certain, the OP said they wanted to match and have since added an edit reinforcing that. They appear to already have the function to replace the accented letters with *.